# Display overlay view when selecting annotation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm using UIRepresentable to show annotations on a map, and want to be able to show a view when tapping on the selected pin.

I was previously using `Map()` so was able to use the `.onTapGesture` for the annotations, but now that the annotations are made from UIKit, how to I pass the selected item to the main view?

What I previously had working:

```swift
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Map(region: $region, annotationItems: $model.locations) { location in
      MapPin(coordinate: location.coord)
        .onTapGesture {
          modelData.selectedLocation = location
          modelData.isShowingDetail = true
        }
    }
    if modelData.isShowingDetail {
      DetailView(
        isShowingDetail: $modelData.isShowingDetail,
        location: modelData.selectedLocation!
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have the UIViewRepresentable:

```swift
struct UIMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

  // default setup - coordinator, makeUI, updateUI

  class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
      // how to trigger the overlay??
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am very stuck on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know the selected annotation in your SwiftUI view. So you have to store it somewhere. Declare a `@State` :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let locations: [MKAnnotation]
    @State private var selectedLocation: MKAnnotation?
    var body: some View {
            // ... //
    }
}
```

Now in your wrapper (`UIViewRepresentable`) you have to make a binding with this `MKAnnotation?` :

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedLocation: MKAnnotation?    // HERE
    let annotations: [MKAnnotation]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.region = // .... //
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        // .... //
    }
```

Now you should be able to access this variable in your Delegate (Coordinator). For that you have to pass the UIViewRepresentable to the Coordinator:

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
```

And finally in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` you can copy the MKAnnotation in `parent.selectedLocation` .
With the `@Binding` this `MKAnnotation` is now accessible in your parent view (`ContentView`). You can display its properties in your `DetailView`.

```
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            // ... //
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            parent.selectedLocation = view.annotation
        }
    }
}
```

For example :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let locations: [MKAnnotation]
    @State private var selectedLocation: MKAnnotation?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(selectedLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)")

            // Don't forget the Binding : $selectedLocation

            MapView(selectedLocation: $selectedLocation, annotations: locations)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {...}` you can have access to functions such as:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
 ...
 }


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) { 
...
}
```

use these (and the others) to do what you do what you want to achieve.